# Powerapps - Make a single field editable and all fields viewable in a Form

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I want to make a single field editable(Display mode.Edit) and make all other fields viewable (FormMode.View) in Powerapps.

Will the FormMode override DisplayMode of fields.?

In my case, when I tried, every fields get viewable when I give FormMode.View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override Edit mode for View mode.
You will need to use disable property of each of your Field on Form to disable it (read only).

[Look into this thread.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Grayed-out-field-based-on-control/td-p/142248)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this is definitely doable.
You can set your form mode to FormMode.Edit, then override the individual DataCards to **DisplayMode.View** instead of **Parent.DisplayMode**  (you may need to unlock the data card):

[image: screenshot]